# JavaScript: Replace last occurrence of forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I've tried fiddling with

```
replace(/_([^_]*)$/,replacement+'$1')
```

from another post but can't get it to work

I have a string:

```
<div class="plus"></div><div class="details"></div>text1/text2
```

that I want to transform into

```
<div class="plus"></div><div class="details"></div>text1/<br>text2
```

but I keep getting the / in /div replaced as well

Anyone?

Edit: To be clear I want to replace the last

```
"/"
```

with

```
"/<br>"
```

only the last occurance.

I dunno... maybe I'm better off going back in my code and try to replace the slash before prepending with html...

Answer (score 2):

Use [lastIndexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp) method

```
var index = str.lastIndexOf('/');
str = str.substr(0, index + 1) + "<br>" + str.substr(index + 1);
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RYhjY/)

Comment: Also working - but again lags the ability to only replace / if its NOT part of an end tag

Comment: @CJe then just make your string as "text1" or "text1/text2" not the whole tags and do this operation

Comment: Done. And then I can use a "normal" replace operation. Thanks.

Comment: @CJe Yupp you can do normal replace ... Good

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
'<div class="plus"></div><div class="details"></div>text1/text2'.replace(/(\/)([^\/]*)$/, '$1' + '<br />' + '$2' )
```

Comment: This might work BUT I just realized that not all strings ends with text containing a forward slash meaning that eg <div class="details"></div>text1 will fail :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you're not trying to capture the slash in the back-reference, add the slash into the text itself:

```
replace(/_([^_]*)$/,replacement+'$1/')
-----------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do that using string methods:

```
var index = str.lastIndexOf('/');
str = str.substr(0, index) + str.substr(index + 1);
```